# PHP how to fetch the current default credentials dynamically with a call to google.auth.default()

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

With python I had to do this to set the right billing ID when building a GCP client (service account and service api in different projects):

```
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient(
    credentials=google.auth.default(quota_project_id=project_id)[0],
)
```

What is the equivalent of `google.auth.default()` for PHP? I can't seem to find a corresponding method.

## Edit

Unsure if I should be using getMiddleware or getCredentials directly, I didn't seen any official docs calling getCredentials directly because getMiddleware calls getCredentials and all the examples use that: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php/blob/main/src/ApplicationDefaultCredentials.php#L127

```
# Call via getMiddleware
$credentials = ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getMiddleware(
    'quotaProject' => 'my-quota-project'
);

# Or just call getCredentials myself?
$credentials = ApplicationDefaultCredentials:: getCredentials(
    'quotaProject' => 'my-quota-project'
);
```

Also, do I need to specify a scope if I don't want to restrict at scope level? I just want all scopes ("cloud-platform").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common methods:

**Use as a static class:**

```
$scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";
$credentials = ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getCredentials($scopes);
```

**Use as a traditional class:**

```
$scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";
$adc = new ApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$credentials = $adc->getCredentials($scopes);
```

**Include this near the top of your source file:**

```
use Google\Auth\ApplicationDefaultCredentials;
```

**Composer:**

```
composer require google/auth
```

I wrote an [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-application-default-credentials-php/) that covers this in detail.

The PHP SDK is located [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php).

Comment: What happens if you don't specify scopes? I thought it just defaulted to cloud-platform, is that not the case?

Comment: I also added to my post asking about the difference between `getMiddleware()` and `getCredentials()`.

Comment: @red888 1) If you do not specify a scope then the credentials will have no permissions. 2) You have modified your original post to ask additional questions. Do not do that. Instead, create a new post(s) for additional questions. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a chat service, post a question, receive an answer, post a new question.

Comment: If you use the middleware feature, you do not need to fetch credentials yourself. The credentials will be automatically added to HTTP requests. My article also discusses that detail.